# Полное игнорирование сервера для подключения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, клиент-сервер

```
public void connectAndRead(){

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.11", 88);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(64);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];

        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            String response1 = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            String[] delims = response1.split("[,]");
            byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
            Double temp = Double.parseDouble(delims[0]);
            Double humidity = Double.parseDouble(delims[1]);
            String res = "Temp = " + temp + "Humidity = " + humidity;
            result.setText(res);
        }


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Суть функции: имеется подключенный сервер, к которому данная функция пытается подключиться и в дальнейшем выводит результат `result.setText(res)`

Ошибка : после строки 
`socket = new Socket("192.168.1.11", 88)` сразу идет `finally`, хотя сервер существует, включен и транслирует данные.

Comment: сразу после этой строки не может быть finally, чтобы выполнился finally, нужно, чтобы сначала выполнились либо один из catch, либо try.

Comment: @Maxgmer, может, если вывалится ошибка, не попадающая ни в один `cath`.

Comment: У Вас разрешение на интернет объявлено? Этот код выполняется в фоновом потоке? Ошибки в логах есть?

Comment: @woesss разве такая ошибка не бросается методом вверх и не вызывает краш?

Comment: @Maxgmer, да, но сначала выполнится `finally`, а потом ошибка будет переброшена выше.

Comment: @woesss Разрешение объявлено, ошибок нет. Код выполняется при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Сетевые операции НЕ должны выполняться в главном потоке. Обработчик нажатия вызывается именно в нём. Используйте [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) или другие решения для асинхронных задач.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо, учту. Но разве AsyncTask позволит мне оставить соединение и постоянно обновлять информацию ? (Я получаю сообщение, данные которого потом вывожу на TextView). У меня почему то выходило, что AsyncTask выполнялся лишь однажды, после чего закрывал соединение

Comment: `AsyncTask` будет работать, пока не дойдёт до конца метод `doInBackground`. Не обязательно использовать именно его. Главное увести работу с сетью из главного потока. Но не забывать, что обращение к UI нужно переводить обратно в главный.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо большое, проблема решена полностью.